# reactjs + how to create a number of elements that are entered via an input

Tags: reactjs

I have a

```
state = {number : 1}
```

which is updated via a form

and I want every time it to add so many `<div />`'s as the number given.

I am thinking that holding in state the divs would be wrong because I wont be able to utilize virtual DOM but I cant think of an alternative

Also I dont want to update the whole DOM but rather compare the previous and add or remove according to the new state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate array of values with length equal to the state number:

```
state = { number: 1 }

get numbers () {
  return Array.from({ length: this.state.number }, (i, _) => _)
}

increment = () => {
  this.setState({ number: this.state.number + 1 })
}
```

Then render divs with usual map:

```
{this.numbers.map(index => (
   <div onClick={this.increment}>{index}</div>
))}
```

**Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/p9w264zklx